# Science fiction story in which African dictator is overthrown by his son

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

This story was written 1984 or earlier, I believe. It was part of the sociological science fiction trend and really had nothing science fiction-like in it other than being set in some unspecified future.

An African dictator is being overthrown and rebel forces are arriving, there are some past memories.

Essentially the dictator was a western agent used in a long running project of building African autonomy, but for sociological/psychological purposes he must be removed because now the population is ready for a completely African democracy and he has too many ties to the corrupt West. This was evidently all planned out. The rebel leader arrives and it is his son who is of course also in on the whole scam and the dictator is sent off to retirement as the glorious revolution will now lead the country to be its own proud and stand alone entity removed from any external manipulative forces.

Does anyone know what story this was? I think it won some award but I can't remember which one or I would just go through the awards lists.